# The verb "piacere" with collective nouns

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, agreement

Using the verb "piacere" with collective nouns: to say 'he doesn't like the people'. Would I say "non gli piace la gente", or "non gli piacciono la gente"?

Comment: Collective nouns are generally singular in Italian. We would say people *is* strange, for example.

Answer (score 9):

Even it's a collective noun, "la gente" is singular. Thus the correct sentence is

> Non gli piace la gente.

Comment: That’s correct. In substandard speech, you may sometimes find the plural agreement with collective singular nouns: “La gente dicono…” But that is considered very sloppy, and an uneducated way of talking, even in speech. In other cases, this kind of agreement is more tolerated, even in writing: e.g. “Un gruppo di studenti sono entrati a scuola”.

Answer (score 5):

You have to accord the verb "piacere" with the subject. Try to think at the phrase like this:

> La gente (singular) non gli piace.
>
> Le persone (plural) non gli piacciono.

Actually "gente" as a collective noun is a bit measleading since its plural is not so common in Italian (genti). You might use "gruppo-gruppi" as an example:

> Gli piace il suo gruppo di amici.
>
> Gli piacciono i gruppi numerosi.

Comment: Non ho ancora sufficiente reputazione per commentare altre domande, ma l'esempio riportato da @Ferdinand Bardamu `“Un gruppo di studenti sono entrati a scuola”` è considerato sbagliato dalla Zanichelli: [link](http://www.zanichellibenvenuti.it/wordpress/?p=3763)

Comment: La concordanza a senso è accettabile anche nello scritto (informale o giornalistico) in molti casi. È uno dei tratti del cosiddetto neostandard. Nei registri piú formali è certamente meglio evitarla. Si veda la voce [«Concordanza a senso»](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/concordanza-a-senso_%28La_grammatica_italiana%29/) nel sito del _Treccani_.